# rotation an image using matlab gui

Tags: matlab, user-interface, image-processing

i am beginner in matlab

i made open button and this is the callback for it:

```
path=imgetfile();
im=imread(path);
axes(handles.frame);
imshow(im);
```

and it work correctly (the image open in axes named frame)

and i made rotate button and this is the callback for it:

```
global im imr
prompt = {'Enter degree of rotate:'};
dlg_title = 'Rotate';
num_lines = 1;
rv = inputdlg(prompt,dlg_title,num_lines);
rv = str2double(rv);
imr=im;
imr=imrotate(imr,rv);
axes(handles.frame);
imshow(imr);
```

Here is the problem ... the image dont rotate

Comment: Is it just rotating only on first click of rotate button ?

Comment: Where is `handles` coming from? Defined or not? Getting any error message? Maybe post the complete code ;.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just declare another global variable in your open button:

```
global im
path=imgetfile();
im=imread(path);
axes(handles.frame);
imshow(im);
```

then in your rotate button,

```
global im 
prompt = {'Enter degree of rotate:'};
dlg_title = 'Rotate';
num_lines = 1;
rv = inputdlg(prompt,dlg_title,num_lines);
rv = str2double(rv);

imr=imrotate(im,rv);
axes(handles.frame);
imshow(imr);
```